# Comparing Learning Algorithms: Choosing Regularization

Tags: regression, least-squares, regularization

I am running a comparison experiment on a set of different algorithms. The test set is the same for all, and there is a pool of items from which each algorithm chooses n items, and then I use ordinary least squares to learn my function, let's call it y(A), where A is the algorithm I used to select the data points.
I'm essentially comparing the quality of the selection algorithms, by comparing predictions made by y(A1), y(A2), ..., y(Am) on the test set.
One of them is a random selection baseline.

For only one of the algorithms, I use weighted least squares instead of OLS. So my question is, should I be using the same regularization across OLS and WLS? Should it be the same for the different selection algorithms that use OLS, or should I tune the regularization for each y(A) individually?
Intuitively it seems that for a fair comparison, regularization should be the same for the algorithms I use OLS with eventually, but I don't know if that's the case in practice, because the random baseline selection outperforms the other more sophisticated selection algorithms. This is disturbing since I am trying to reproduce results from a paper and this is definitely not the observed trend there.